# How to use text box user entered data in a JS Function and loop

Tags: javascript, html

My code sort of works correctly but I want to tweak it and cannot seem to build the way I expect. Basically I have two labels and input. Ask user to enter a certain number of weeks (in the code I have kept it at 3 but intend on going out longer) and number of days for each week entered supplement packs were taken. Button is clicked and a function is called. I want the function to prompt the user to enter the number of packs for each day they were taken (if 2 weeks were entered and they only took supplements 3x a week I only want to iterate through the prompt 3 days for week-1 and 3 days for week-2). As each day is entered the information is output back to the screen and a subtotal for each week is given. For a beginner I think I've learned quite a bit and mostly due to this site. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Supplement Intake Log</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--JS Code here-->
<script>
    function getPho() {
    var week = document.getElementById("week").value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var numPacks = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;
    week = parseInt(week);
    day = parseInt(day);
        for(week = 1; week < 3; week++)
        {
            document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML="Week " + week + "
<br>";
            count = 1; 
            subtotal = 0;
            for(day = 1; day < 8; day++)
            {
                numPacks = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of packs for 
week " + week + " and day " + day + " . ", ""));
                document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML+="Number of 
packs for day " + day + " = " + numPacks + " supplement packs."+ "<br>";
                subtotal = subtotal + numPacks;
                count++;
            }
            total = total + subtotal;
            document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML="Week " + week + " 
subtotal is " + subtotal + " supplement packs." + "<br>";
        }
            document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML="The total for 
these weeks is " + total + " supplment packs." + "<br>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>Weekly Supplement Intake Log</h1></header>
<section>
<label>Number of weeks on supplements:</label>
<input type="text" name="week" id="week" value=""><br>
<label>Number of days supplements taken each week:</label>
<input type="text" name="day" id="day" value="">

<div id="button">
<button type="button" id="calc" onClick="getPho()">Enter the number of  
 packs taken each day/week</button></div>
<div id="output1"></div> 
<div id="output2"></div> 
<div id= "output3"></div>

<div id="output4"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of hard coding in week < 3, if you want to iterate only over the number of weeks entered it should be something like week < week, also change your counter variable to something else so its not confused with the variable you assign to the text input. for(i=1; i < week; i++) {...}

Comment: Please explain (EDIT) your requirement comprehensively so that you get a quick-answer @allendks45

Comment: What i want after the page is rendered is for data to be entered as number of weeks and number of days each of those weeks supplements were taken. User clicks button and a prompt asks to enter the number of supplement packs for each of the days entered in the textfield box. Each prompt is then shown on screen as some text and the number of packs for each of the days. A subtotal is displayed for each week that was entered. @brian thanks...not sure why I didn't change that already. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: If the user entered 2 weeks and took supplements for 4 days each week the prompt would only allow (ask for that data and store it until called in the subtotal). then it would output to screen for each day number of packs....ie; day 1 "blank" packs of supplements were taken...and iterate through for each of the 4-days. I plan on expanding this to more weeks and days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiddle will loop through the weeks and for each week loop through the days per week taken and ask the user for an input of number of packs taken per day.

```
    var i=0;
while(i<numWeeks) {
    var d=0;
    while(d<daysPerWeek){
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auco824j/2/

Comment: Nested while loops is the way to go! I was determined to use the nested for loops but this is much cleaner and simpler. Think I'll expand this small  program a bit and see what the results are. Thanks!